# In which use case Multiple renderer is used in Dispatcher

Tags: aem

I am trying to understand when it make sense to use multiple renderer in dispatcher.any configuration. For example I have this setup.

On Dispatcher-1 server:

```
  /renders {
   /0001 {
    /hostname "https://publish-1.com"
    /port "8443"
      }
  /0002 {
    /hostname "https://publish-2.com"
    /port "8443"
      }
  }
```

On Dispatcher-2 server:

```
  /renders {
   /0001 {
    /hostname "https://publish-1.com"
    /port "8443"
      }
  /0002 {
    /hostname "https://publish-2.com"
    /port "8443"
      }
  }
```

Now as per my understanding dispatcher will forward the traffic to either publish-1 or publish-2 server depending on the time taken by the respective publish server.

When I look into this [page](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/administering/using/encapsulated-token.html) then I see there is no configuration which makes it possible to direct the traffic from Dispatcher-1 to Publish-2. It is always Dispatcher-1 to Publish-1 or Dispatcher-2 to Publish-2. If Publish-2 goes down then the request landing on Dispatcher-2 will not be processed.

Could you please clarify what is the use of only one-to-one setup and when it make sense to have one-to-many setup?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

From your link

> With stateful authentication, the persisted authentication state will only be available on the instance where the user is first authenticated.

This is the key. Since Publishers B & C don’t know about the authenticated request, and sessions are not shared between the application servers, all subsequent requests need to be “sticky” to Publisher A. This is maintained by the load balancer, not the dispatcher.

As a result, the dispatcher in front of Publisher A is 1:1 mapped to a single node rather than many.

Comment: Thanks, how is it possible to do 1 to many and in which use case would you setup 1:many ?

Comment: There is a stanza for your render farm in the apache/dispatcher configs [documented here](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-dispatcher/using/configuring/dispatcher-configuration.html#renders-options) | If you put in multiple renderers (aka publishers) the dispatcher will act as a load balancer (albeit a poor one in my opinion)

Comment: As for use cases - if you have a low load / high cache hit type of site that does not NEED an incredibly robust or intelligent load balancer, 2 dispatchers mapped to 2 publishers sets you up for a pretty good high availability site. If 1 dispatcher or 1 publisher (or one of each) goes down, your site is still up at a lower capacity. This is all purely situational though and subjective.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again, why do you think dispatcher as a load balance is a bad idea, if you have real time experience then could you please share what challenges did you face?

Comment: Personally, I would avoid the one to many, and use the 1:1 approach, and leave the work of balancing to a proper load balance. From experience, the risk is that if a publish instance fails, then all the dispatchers using it as a render will suffer, with the 1:1 approach you isolate the issue and can easily remove the problematic pair.